# Change checkbox status on click is not being displayed

Tags: javascript, checkbox, d3.js

Checkbox status values are stored in localStorage. 'updateStorage' sets these key value pairs to 'null' in localStorage.

The effect is seen only after page reload. How can I achieve the change of the checkbox status to be displayed directly, such as in toggle, after the function is invoked ?

```
d3.select("#update").on("click",updateStorage);


function updateStorage(){

var updatethis = d3.selectAll(".box").each(function(){

var use_it = this.id;

localStorage.setItem(use_it,null);
d3.select(this).property('checked', null); //does not change display directly

});
};
```

Adding this line did not help

```
     d3.select(this).property('checked', null);
```

Do I need a transition ??

Comment: Have you tried using the `change` event to trigger your function?

Comment: It is a button that resets all checkboxes to unchecked on that page; have tried change and click on that button. The localStorage action works fine. All checkboxes are set to null, but the display does not change unless page reload.

Comment: It seems logical with the code that I have but I would like to toggle the checkboxes visually as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I solved it like this:

```
d3.select("#update").on("click",updateStorage);


function updateStorage(){

var updatethis = d3.selectAll(".box").filter(":checked").each(function(){

var use_it = this.id;
console.log("updatethisid :" + use_it);
d3.selectAll('.box').property('checked', false);
localStorage.setItem(use_it,null);


});
};
```

I am not sure why I cannot select the boxes with d3.select(this) to the same effect. - ?

I added a filter with pseudo :checked to select the checked boxes only.